# Implementing Java DAO Pattern on the Same JVM

Tags: java, design-patterns, dao

This question is related to the core understanding of the Java DAO Pattern. Please look at a simple [java dao pattern example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/data_access_object_pattern.htm) to understand my question.

At line 2 below, the student object has already been altered with a new name, what is the point of line three if both the client and the backend are running under the same JVM?

In my humble understanding of the DAO pattern, the client must only alter data using services, such as the studentDao below, and the client shouldn't have the possibility of altering the value object (pojo) directly. But when both the client and the backend service run under the same JVM, and client gets a POJO with normal setters, why does the client need to call the service?

Are there any best practices to implement a DAO pattern where the client can and must only consume/alter data using dao-services? A very example would be great to look at.

```
//update student
1. Student student =studentDao.getAllStudents().get(0);
2. student.setName("Michael");
3. studentDao.updateStudent(student);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, what does it mean on same JVM. If your DAO uses DB, then the object won't change in DB when you change POJO. Similarly, when other thread will load the same entity, the new POJO will be created based on the DB content (unless your DAO makes some special caching) => no problem.

So for now let's assume that you build some kind of in-memory DAO. If not implemented properly, in such case change on POJO can "effect" other clients as you have already pointed out. However this is not good implementation of DAO - so you have to take care that POJOs accessible by clients can't have impact DAO "state". The easiest way to do so is always return [defensive copies](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=15) for both all returned values but also for all inputs (insert, update etc).

Comment: Yes, by "same JVM" I actually what you point out; there is only a single representation of the object, and anybody with a reference to it can actually change it. In the example, would that be a good idea to create a duplicate class called StudentDTO with no setter methods which is sent to the client by the service studentDao?

Comment: but DAO pattern does not dictate that entity objects can't be changed. the only point is that "the persisted representation" can't be changed outside the DAO. In your example Student object can be changed with setter. However alternative aproach to defensive copies is use of imutable objects.

Comment: Yes, immutable object are to prefer, but most of the time we need setters to change state of an object during it's lifetime. So I liked the method of defensive copy or deep copy of the object, such as using copy constructors. Then the client can call the setter to the change the object, but must use the DAO-service to actually make change to the original object.

Comment: if you like immutable objects. check also builder pattern: http://cantina.co/immutable-objects-and-the-builder-pattern/